# Increment e009 to e010 using java

Tags: java

I have a table with fields like empNo, Name , etc.
and i want java to generate numbers automatically.
for eg. if the number of the last employee was e009,
java should give me the number for the next one as e010.

I tried this and it works well but seems tedious.

```
     rs.last();
     String no,temp;
     no = rs.getString(1);      
     int len = no.length();
     len=len-1;
     int n = Integer.parseInt(no.substring(1,no.length()));
     n=n+1;
     int length = (int)(Math.log10(n)+1);
     no="E";
     for(int i=1;i<=len-length;i++)
        no=no+"0";
     no=no+n;
     txtNo.setText(no);
```

Comment: Think about the problem... If you have the number of the last employee in a variable, how do you get the next employee's number?

Comment: Simple string parsing: substring, parse, concat.

Comment: And I want a pony.  _What is your question?_

Comment: I've edited the question based on my approach. Please suggest now

Answer (score 0):

Have a static counter variable inside the class that represents your table's row. In its constructor, assign the empNo value to the value of the counter. 
You could also add formatting to make the number a fixed size of, say, 3 in another method or within the constructor itself.

And don't forget to increment the counter within the constructor.

Comment: A mutable static variable may not be the best solution, because it would introduce a singleton (which is an anti-pattern). You may just want to keep track of the counter in the code that calls the constructor.

Comment: I've edited the question based on my approach. Please suggest now